# Downgraded image in pin description

Tags: android, google-maps

[Hope I'm in the right forum. This question is regarding a problem in the use of this API]

I encounter the following problem with the Google Maps API on my android phone. I create a map in my pc, add a pin, and then add a high resolution image in the description space for this pin. The image is displayed excellently on my pc or netbook, but when I access the map with my phone, through Google Maps API, I press on the pin's name to see the description, and the image is shown severely downgraded in quality (although it maintains it's original size in height and width).
Any thoughts please?

Comment: I guess from your description that your not using Google Maps v2 for Android to create a map in Activity/Fragment. In which way you're "access the map with my phone"?

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I really couldn't find any support for the API, nor e-mail or forum of any short. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2824859 This is **probably** the right site to ask your question, but you need to specify what exactly is your problem (some code snippets would help).

Comment: MaciejGórski I am not a programmer. Just a user.